# In nuSOAP, how to return simple data type having multiple occurance as response?

Tags: nusoap

Suppose my response message can be like this

```
<Response> 
<ResponseCode>false</ResponseCode> 
<ResponseMessage>reason 1</ResponseMessage> 
<ResponseMessage>reason 2</ResponseMessage> 
<ResponseMessage>reason 3</ResponseMessage> 
</Response>
```

this (xsd:string) item is having multiple occurance.

How to add and configure this kind of rsponse message in nuSOAP server?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this example on another forum. It helped me solving a similar issue with multiple elements:

```
<inventory>
    <car>
        <make>Nissan</make>
        <model>Maxima</model>
        <year>2005</year>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
    </car>
    <car>
        <make>Nissan</make>
        <model>Maxima</model>
        <year>2006</year>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </car>
</inventory>
```

NuSOAP takes the approach that "car", which is repeated, is an array, so 
the "car" element in the associative array points to a simple array:

```
$car[] = array('make' => 'Nissan', 'model' => 'Maxima', 'year' => 2005, 
'quantity' => 3);
$car[] = array('make' => 'Nissan', 'model' => 'Maxima', 'year' => 2006, 
'quantity' => 1);


$inventory = array('car' => $car);
```